# Instagram redirect URI does not match registered URI IOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I have my outgoing and incoming URI's

```
self.outgoingRedirect = @"https://courseera.com";
self.incomingRedirect = @"https://myscheme.com";
```

and the rest of the code looks like this-

```
   [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] 
   setClientID:@"xxx"
  secret:@"xxx"
authorizationURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:@"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize"]
tokenURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:@"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"]
redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.outgoingRedirect] 
forAccountType:@"Instagram"];
```

return YES;
}

```
(BOOL) application:(UIApplication )app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:
(NSDictionary *)options{

if([self.incomingRedirect containsString:[url scheme] ] && 
[self.incomingRedirect containsString:[url host]]){

NSURL *constructed = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@",self.outgoingRedirect,[url query]]];
NSLog(@"We received a callback URL");
return [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] 
handleRedirectURL:constructed];
}

else{

return [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] handleRedirectURL:url];
}
};
```

I am getting an error as "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI."

Comment: What redirect URI did you input in the Instagram dev portal for your app?

Comment: I have added the URI as http://myscheme.com

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Instagram is just redirecting you to `myscheme.com`. Instead what you need to do set ur `redirectURI` to `https://myscheme.com/instagram.html?igCLIENTID://authorize` and in your project set ur `redirect uri` for `instagram` to be `igCLIENTID://authorize` and on ur myScheme website when the `instagram.html` webpage is hit attempt to redirect to `igCLIENTID://authorize` ios will recognise this and know that ur app will handle this and will launch ur app. Instagram has only started doing this previously you could have non `https` `redirect uri` but that is no longer the case.